# How to find out why an "always free" instance was deleted?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

My *always free* instance has been deleted without any warning or notification whatsoever.

There doesn't seem to be any way at all to talk to anyone at Oracle about this.  Their support redirects to [Cloud Customer Connect](http://ccc.ociforums.com/?source=:ow:o:s:nav:062520GlobalNavProducts), but that refuses you let to post anything new until you update your Display Name, and then when you do, it still complains that you need to do this.  They also direct people to ask questions in StackOverflow tagged with *oracle-cloud-infrastructure* which is what I am doing now.

Oracle seem to be working hard to make *always free* *unreliably free*.

Anyone have any advise how I can find out why this was deleted?

Or another provider of low-resource Linux VM instances on a "free" tier.

Comment: This is off-topic for StackOverflow as it is not programming related. You need to talk to Oracle support.

Comment: If you say so, but Oracle is redirecting people here for questions about their Cloud Infrastructure.  Perhaps you (or somebody with authority to do so) should ask them to stop doing that.

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming related questions; if you such a question relating to Oracle Cloud Infrastructure then you can ask it but, in general, most OCI questions are not going to relate to programming and are going to be customer service questions (which we can't answer, as random people on the internet are not Oracle customer service) or about setting up OCI (which is off topic). If Oracle is redirecting people here then perhaps you, as a customer, should point them ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) so only relevant questions are asked.